# Spring data timeout based batch insert of data

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, batch-processing

I have a spring boot app that receives data from different devices that I need to insert as batch to maximize performance. For this I have considered storing data in memory for a while and then calling build in spring data saveAll method to save as a batch. But the my problem is that data does not come at a regular speed and I may get a few thousand data at a time and then no data for next few hours. So I am not sure how to properly build the batch as there may be few data at the end that would be left out with a fixed sized batch. Is there a way to do a timed batching in java/spring that flushes the batch after a configured timeout?

Comment: How is this data coming to the app? Is app pooling the devices for the data? Or the client(devices) send the data to the app using some API? Or there is some queue setup from where app reads the data?

Comment: The data arrives on a subscribed mqtt topic. Each data is currently processed and saved in a separate thread from a threadpool.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing this using BlockingQueue and Guauva's Queues.drain

```
executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String first = queue.take();
                    List<String> output = new LinkedList<>();
                    output.add(first);
                    Queues.drain(queue, output, BATCH_SIZE - 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    repo.saveAll(output);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Where I am doing queue.add() from the producer thread